# Выполнение функции только при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: php

Функция сама выполняется при входе на страницу, нужно её выполнить только при нажатии на кнопку.

```
$emailp = $_POST['email'];

$sqlemail = 'INSERT INTO user(email)VALUES("'.$emailp.'")';

if(!mysql_query($sqlemail))
 {echo '<center><p><b>Ошибка при добавлении данных!</b></p></center>';}
 else
 {echo '<center><p><b>Данные добавлены!</b></p></center>';}

//

<form method="post" action="/?page=profile">
    Введите E-mail: <input type="text" size="45" name="emailp">
<input type="submit" value="Указать E-mail">
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Решил. Обернул всё в

```
if($_POST){ }
```

Comment: Если сделать post запрос, но не передать поле email, будет notice. Если передать в email специально сформированный запрос, можно сделать, например, drop table или drop database.

Answer (score 2):

Это неверно.

```
if(isset($_POST['email']))
```

Иначе будут notice. Кстати, советую включить отображение всех ошибок и начать учиться правильно кодить.